# Simulate the pressing of the "Command" key on a Mac

Tags: java, macos

I am currently trying to create a tamogatchi game in java, however, I need a method to clear the output screen so that the healthbar/foodbar goes down while staying in the same position. I found that pressing Command+L (on a Mac) will clear the output. However, I am unable to find the KeyEvent command for it. This is what I currently have

```
package tamogatchu;

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Tamogatchu {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
        initialize();
    }

    public static void initialize() throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
        int full = 10;
        int health = 10;
        int happy = 10;
        int idk = 0;
        int poop = 0;
        String[] food = new String[10];
        String[] healthbar = new String[10];
        String[] happyness = new String[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            food[i] = "◼";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            healthbar[i] = "◼";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            happyness[i] = "◼";
        }
        Print(food, full, healthbar, health, idk, happyness, happy, poop);

    }

    public static void tamogatchu(String[] food, int full, String[] healthbar, int health, int idk, String[] happyness, int happy, int poop) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
        //int timer = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String care = "";
        String hungery = "";
        String healthery = "";
        String happery = "";

        while (health > 0) {
            if (full != 0) {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } else {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }

            Robot r = new Robot();
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
            // the command⌘ key should be pressed here r.keyPress(KeyEvent.);
            //r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);

            String Line = Arrays.toString(food);
            String result = Line.replaceAll("[-+.^:, ]", "");
            hungery = "Hunger: " + result;
            System.out.println(hungery);

            String Line2 = Arrays.toString(healthbar);
            String result2 = Line2.replaceAll("[-+.^:, ]", "");
            healthery = "Health: " + result2;
            System.out.println(healthery);

            String Line3 = Arrays.toString(happyness);
            String result3 = Line3.replaceAll("[-+.^:, ]", "");
            happery = "Happieness: " + result3;
            System.out.println(happery);

            if (idk == 0) {

                System.out.println("  .^._.^.\n"
                        + "  | . . |\n"
                        + " (  ---  )\n"
                        + " .'     '.\n"
                        + " |/     \\|\n"
                        + "  \\ /-\\ /\n"
                        + "   V   V");
                idk = 1;

            } else {

                System.out.println("  .^._.^.\n"
                        + "  | . . |\n"
                        + " (  ---  )\n"
                        + " |/     \\|\n"
                        + "  \\ /-\\ /\n"
                        + "   V   V");
                idk = 0;
            }
            System.out.println("Poops: " + poop);

            System.out.println("take care of your pet?  -type 'feed' to feed or 'clean' to get rid of poops-");
            care = input.nextLine();
            if (care.equalsIgnoreCase("feed")) {
                full += 5;
                if (full > 10) {
                    full = 10;
                }
            } else if (care.equalsIgnoreCase("clean")) {
                poop = 0;
            }
            if (full % 2 == 0) {
                poop++;
                happy -= poop;
            }
            if (full > 7 && health < 10 || full > 5 || poop == 0) {
                if (full > 7 && health < 10) {
                    health++;
                    if (health > 10) {
                        health = 10;
                    }
                }
                if (full > 5) {
                    happy++;
                    if (happy > 10) {
                        happy = 10;
                    }
                }
                if (poop == 0) {
                    happy++;
                    if (happy > 10) {
                        happy = 10;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (full != 0) {
                full--;
                if (full <= 5) {
                    happy--;
                }

                if (full == 0) {
                    happy--;
                    health--;
                } else if (happy == 0) {
                    health--;
                }

                Print(food, full, healthbar, health, idk, happyness, happy, poop);
            }

            if (full == 0 || happy == 0) {

                if (full == 0) {
                    happy--;
                    health--;
                } else if (happy == 0) {
                    health--;
                }
                Print(food, full, healthbar, health, idk, happyness, happy, poop);

            }


        }

        System.out.println("Hunger: [◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻]");
        System.out.println("Health: [◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻]");
        System.out.println("Happieness: [◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻]");
        System.out.println("  .^._.^.\n"
                + "  | x x |\n"
                + " (  ---  )\n"
                + " .'     '.\n"
                + " |/     \\|\n"
                + "  \\ /-\\ /\n"
                + "   V   V");

        System.out.println("YOU KILLED IT");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void Print(String[] food, int full, String[] healthbar, int health, int idk, String[] happyness, int happy, int poop) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
        for (int i = 0; i < full; i++) {
            food[i] = "◼";
        }
        if (-1 + full >= 0) {
            for (int i = 9; i > -1 + full; i--) {
                food[i] = "◻";
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                food[i] = "◻";
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < health; i++) {
            healthbar[i] = "◼";
        }
        for (int i = 9; i > -1 + health; i--) {
            healthbar[i] = "◻";
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < happy; i++) {
            happyness[i] = "◼";
        }
        if (-1 + happy >= 0) {
            for (int i = 9; i > -1 + happy; i--) {
                happyness[i] = "◻";
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                happyness[i] = "◻";
            }
        }
        tamogatchu(food, full, healthbar, health, idk, happyness, happy, poop);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class, the name for <kbd>Command</kbd>(⌘) is `KeyEvent.VK_META`. Your code should look like this:

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META); //press command
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L); //press l
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META); //release command
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L); //release l
```

This presses the <kbd>Command</kbd> key, presses the <kbd>L</kbd> key, then releases them both. I have tested this, and it works as it should.

NOTE: Using `Robot` throws `AWTException`, so it requires you to either surround with try-catch block, or throw `AWTException` in your method header

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553913/switching-apps-on-mac-with-awt-robot-only-sometimes-works as this bare solution did not work for me