# Switching Apps on Mac with AWT Robot only sometimes works

Tags: java, macos, javafx, awt, awtrobot

I'm trying to use Robot in order to switch apps, and then enter some text. To do this (on my mac), I'm pressing Meta, Tab, and then releasing Tab, Meta in this order:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
```

This works, but only occasionally (about every 5 or six presses). I've tried calling Thread.wait() inbetween press and release, but this has no effect. Neither does trying to mask Tab with META_DOWN_MASK. I also tried using the JavaFX Robot (com.sun.glass.ui.Robot), but the JavaFX version doesn't work at all.

Comment: `com.sun.glass.ui.Robot` is not a JavaFX specific implementation. It is more of an internal API used by the JDK, as far as I know. It is not meant to be used directly.

Comment: @Jai Does the glass Robot still rely on AWT though? I'm using JavaFX, and it's a real shame to have to pull in all of AWT just for the Robot class. there seems to be proposals for making the api public (https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8090763# and https://gist.github.com/brcolow/26370db6cab0355186d4a1d13b30fc19). Unfortunately there's no delay functionality, though.

Answer (score 1):

Ah.. Seems that I need to specify a delay between the events. Updated:

```
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
            robot.delay(300);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
```