# Robot paste from Clipboard types "v"

Tags: java

(OSX) I am trying to paste the String "Hello World!" onto a seperate application from my Clipboard. The String gets copied to my Clipboard and I can paste it manually, but the robot only types "v" rather than pressing the VK_META + VK_V keys simultaneously.

```
public static void sendString() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    String text = "Hello World!";
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(text);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
    } catch(java.awt.AWTException awte) {
        System.out.println("AWTException");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a `delay()`.

Comment: Try `Robot.delay(500)` between the presses and releases

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48553913/1553851

Comment: A `robot.Delay(500)` after the first keyPress resolved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure the *order of commands*, add a delay between them :

```
try{
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
    robot.delay(500);                    // 200~500
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
} catch(java.awt.AWTException awte) {
    System.out.println("AWTException");
}
```